# Retrieve GIT Revision value as parameter in Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins

Is there a way to get the GIT Revision value as Jenkins variable.

Console log contains the  line with Revision:

Commencing build of Revision bccb1185a524039f5906fbc15969b33105e04702 (origin/master

I found the variable ${GIT_REVISION} . Is this correct ?

Comment: Oh come on, it's in the first hit if you google the title. You're meant to do at least a little research before asking other people.

Comment: I found something like this ${GIT_REVISION} ?

Comment: google: "GIT Revision value as parameter in Jenkins", then click the first result (git parameter plugin), then read the page all the way to the bottom.

Comment: @Engineer Dollery  : Still no correct answer from you.

Comment: Jenkins Git plugin documentation describing the parameters can be found at https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin

Answer (score 2):

${GIT_COMMIT} is the correct answer I think.